# Indexing properties without storing them

Tags: arangodb

In Solr, for example, it is possible to index fields of documents without storing them. Is something similar possible in arangodb?

For example, lets have a document, which has a pdf attached to it. I want to be able index the content of the pdf so I can find the document when searching terms in the pdf, but the content should not be stored in the document itself.

Can I do that with arangodb?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you asking for a memory-only index (volatile and not persisted at all), or for virtual/computed fields held in memory but not stored in documents? In the latter scenario, how would these fields be computed at all?

Comment: The data has to get into an index in order for you to leverage the power of an index. You could extract the contents of the PDF and store them as text within the ArangoDB document, but it does need to be stored in ArangoDB if you want an index to see the data.

Comment: @DavidThomas It has to be stored in the document to be indexed. That's what I needed to know. Thanks David.

Comment: If you're storing a PDF, I'll assume you store it as a base64 encoded blob? Indexes run on base data types, so a base64 blob would be a string. ArangoDB doesn't have custom indexers that lets you natively index data from other data formats, other than the native formats available to ArangoDB, e.g. string, number, etc

Comment: @DavidThomas At the moment we use Solr to index the content of PDFs as a string. In Solr you can mark a field as `indexed=true; stored=false`. This way you can still find the corresponding document but the content of the PDF is only indexed, not stored.
In Arango we would do something similar. Extract the content of the PDF and store it as a string in Arango to be able to index it.

Comment: Then yes, you'd be able to index it in ArangoDB for sure then, as it supports indexes on strings. You'll just have to ensure you generate the index manually, as Arango can't natively extract it from a PDF.